# Do we need to explicitly ask for the permission other than AndroidManifest.xml in Marshmallow?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

In the Android versions lower than the marshmallow, i can run my application that writes a file to the External storage. And in those system the permission is granted at the time of installation of the app. But when i tried to run my application in marshmallow, it says "the app need no permissions" at the time of installation. And the app unexpectedly exits at the time i execute the write function.

Usually the device asks to grant permissions on every app at the time when it is opened for the first time. but in my app this too doesn't happens.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the runtime permission handling for Android 6.0+ (Marshmallow) yourself. See [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) for more information.